# data lost from database after closing the emulator

Tags: android, database

My program contains a database class. I retrieve data from database to listview and the code works.But when i close the emulator and reopen it all the data are lost. Database class is given.Please help me to make the necessary changes in the code for the data persistance.

classdbOpenHelper.java

```
package example.events1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class classdbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_DESC = "countdesc";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "countdate";
    public static final String KEY_EVENT = "countevent";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME= "countdb";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "countable";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    public classdbOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
                + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_DESC + " TEXT, " + KEY_DATE + " TEXT, " + KEY_EVENT + " TEXT  )";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXITS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }


    public Cursor fetchAllEvents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_DESC, KEY_DATE, KEY_EVENT },
        null, null, null, null, null );
        if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
   }

    public Cursor fetchEventByName(String inputText,String datevalue ) throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor mCursor = null;
        if (inputText == null || inputText.length () == 0) {
        mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_DESC, KEY_DATE, KEY_EVENT },
        null, null, null, null, null);
        }
        else {
            mCursor  =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM countable WHERE countdesc = ? AND countdate = ?", new String[] {inputText,datevalue});           
        }

        if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
   }

    public void delete(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id )});
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: when u re open emulator unchecked the option -"wipe user data" if it is checked.

Comment: @Indiandroid where is this option in eclipse

Comment: check Umar's answer u have to make change in ur code..and it is in toolbar(android device manager)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_DESC + " TEXT, " + KEY_DATE + " TEXT, " + KEY_EVENT + " TEXT  )";
```

To

```
  String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_DESC + " TEXT, " + KEY_DATE + " TEXT, " + KEY_EVENT + " TEXT  )";
```

The reason your DB is empty whenever your `app/activity` is completely destroyed (i-e; when the phone/emulator restarts), is because `you haven't specified the conditions` for when to create the DB and when not. By making the above changes your problems should be long gone

Comment: @UmerFarooq wrong answer, if you need to do "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" that means your programming(code structure) is bad... actually if you properly design your database code, you don't need to take case whether a table exists or not already